# Scanner.skip() in Java

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and trying to understand the Scanner class. I'm using the [example code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_skip_pattern.htm) to learn about the skip(String Pattern) method of the Scanner class. I tweaked the code a little and changed it to

```
import java.util.*;

public class ScannerDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true ";

      // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

      // changed the string to skip
      scanner.skip("World");

      // print a line of the scanner
       System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());

      // close the scanner
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

The output I was expecting is

```
Hello ! 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true
```

But I get `NoSuchElementException`. Can some one point out my mistake please.

Comment: Hi Donal. I tried that too. I used scanner.next() in a while loop but I get the same Exception

Comment: From the Javadoc: "If a match to the specified pattern is not found at the current position, then no input is skipped and a NoSuchElementException is thrown"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not nextLine that is giving you exception, but the skip("World").

When the Scanner start, it is pointing to the "H" in "Hello Word...", that is the first letter.

Then you tell him to skip, and must give a regulare expression for the skip.

Now, a good regular expression to skip to after the word "World" is :

```
scanner.skip(".*World");
```

".*World" means "Every character any number of times followed by World".

This will move the scanner to the "!" after the "Hello World", so nextLine() will return

```
! 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true
```

The "Hello" part has been skipped, as per skip.

Comment: So the skip method always skips something in the beginning and not something in middle of a stream?

Comment: The skip method (and in general the Scanner itself) moves forward.

Comment: @Sanket "*skips something in the beginning and not something in middle of a stream?*" not from *beginning*, but from *current position* of scanners cursor. For instance if you use `nest()` than `skip(".*World!")` and than `nextLine()` you will get `Hello` and `3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Scanner` source String is pointing to the first word in the String which is `Hello`. To get the expected output its probably simpler just to remove the word from the String

```
s = s.replace("World", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Scanner to get that out put? You can easily use replace method in the Strings

```
s = s.replace("World", "");
```